# EnityManager won't delete records if I put it in a Runnable

Tags: jsf-2, executorservice, hibernate-entitymanager

I searched for some answer to my question on this site; but failed on every turn. I can delete fine if I don't put this in a ExecutorService, but if I do, it doesn't delete. No error occurs just the records are still in the database. Please advise.

```
 public void deleteAllTrials(List<Trials>list) { 
      threadList = list;
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
      executor.execute(new Job1());
      executor.shutdown();
```

}

```
 public class Job1 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
            EntityManagerFactory emf = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            System.out.println("Size of threadList" + threadList.size());
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

            for(int i =0; i<threadList.size(); i++){
                System.out.println("In thread...");

                       Trials mergedEntity = em.merge(threadList.get(i));
                em.remove(mergedEntity);
            }
            //System.out.println("Result list in service:" + list.size());
            //em.close();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Threads took this long:" + (end - start));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Normal you need a transaction for it. em.getTransaction().begin(); ...merge, remove etc. ...em.getTransaction().commit();

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Thanks for the reply. I took you advise and I received this error, "A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()" The "entityManager" variable was initialized by the PersistenceContext annotation with a jta-data-source tag or something. In the app we normally don't need to use getTransactions() and such and commit is done automatically

Comment: Ah okay... couldnt see this from the code above. I didnt work with several threads + entitymanager. You could read here hope it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888040/java-an-entitymanager-object-in-a-multithread-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that EJBs are more powerful than I thought. If you just add @Asynchronus on top of the method you want the application to separate in a backing thread, it will be acting as a separate thread allowing the user to continue doing what he wants to do without waiting on the process to finish.

```
 @Asynchronous
 public void deleteAllTrials(List<TrialBillet>list) { 
     List<TrialBillet> threadList = new ArrayList<TrialBillet>();
      threadList = list;
      for(int i =0; i<threadList.size(); i++){
         this.delete(threadList.get(i));
      }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with Executors, [java-ee-7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/concurrency-utilities002.htm#CIHFBCFH) has introduced [ManagedExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html)

> **From Java EE 7 tutorial**
>
> ManagedExecutorService: A managed executor service is used by
>   applications to execute submitted tasks asynchronously. **Tasks are
>   executed on threads that are started and managed by the container.** The
>   context of the container is propagated to the thread executing the
>   task. For example, by using an ManagedExecutorService.submit() call, a
>   task, such as the GenerateReportTask, could be submitted to execute at
>   a later time and then, by using the Future object callback, retrieve
>   the result when it becomes available.

code sample:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Resource
    private ManagedExecutorService mes;


    public void myMethod() {
        mes.execute(new Worker());
    }
}
```