# Should there be an EntityManager per thread in Spring-Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

We are designing an application using Spring-Hibernate where 6 threads run simultaneously. Each thread performs a different operation and inserts/updates a few records in common table(all threads work on common tables).

While we know that we can have just one single instance of `EntityManagerFactory`, we are not sure how many instances of `EntityManager` should we have? Should we create six entity managers(one for each thread)? How should we create the DAO? Should we just create one `EntityManager` like following and use the same dao class for all the threads? I know EM specification says that it's not thread safe, but I read somewhere that injected EM in the case of spring are threadsafe(I wasn't convinced with the explanation, though).

```
@Trasactional
public class myAppDao { 
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
..
}
```

or should we do something different ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888040/java-an-entitymanager-object-in-a-multithread-environment

Comment: `Entity managers are not thread-safe But, if the injector is injecting each thread with its own entity manager then things should be OK.Spring and possibly other DI frameworks will inject a ThreadLocal-based proxy for a real entity manager into your beans. Calls that each thread makes will proxy to the real thread-local instance of an entity manager - this is how things can work even though it might appear an entity manager is shared among multiple threads.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, usually the `EntityManager` or `Session` are bound to the thread (implemented as a ThreadLocal variable). `@PersistenceContext` annotation is recognized by Spring IoC/CDI and is treated in a special way to enable this.

There is some layer in your app (usually marked as `@Transactional`) that creates EntityManager and binds it to the ThreadLocal variable. This happens every time the 1st `@Transactional` is invoked. And same - `EntityManager` is closed every time the method exits.

Alternatively this can be implemented using `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` or `OpenSessionInViewFilter`.

Comment: So can I just create one Dao class in which I initialize an EM and inject that dao to all other classes where each class has its own thread?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget that the invocation should go through `@Transactional` method.

Comment: Yes sure. Thank you very much.

Comment: Should i use **@Transactional** for methods that their job are finding data(not changing) to make the container to close EM?

Comment: @Arash, yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539213/why-do-i-need-transaction-in-hibernate-for-read-only-operations/13540484#13540484